# BUILD FAILED com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i know there are many solutions on this like removing platform and then re-adding a particular version of it , i removed platform and then added android@6.1.2 that showed me error `"wrapper not found you need to update sdk`" so i run ionic add platform android@6.2.2 and now Im getting this error mentioned below,

```
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResourcesF:\ionic\iitk-convocation-2017\platforms\android\build\int
ermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resourc
e found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
     FAILED

F:\ionic\iitk-convocation-2017\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\
debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches
 the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.871 secs
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt





 I am using 
    Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
    Ionic Version: 1.3.3
    Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.0
    Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.16
    OS: Windows 7 SP1
    Node Version: v6.11.1
```

Comment: " you need to update sdk" probably means android sdk and build tools

Comment: but when i run ionic platform add android@6.2.2 I was getting build failed with exception ,that i have mentioned above ,what Should I do for this error?

Comment: One of the libraries is using resources from a newer API. You need to update your compile SDK version to a newer one (looks like at least 26).

Comment: I added platform 8 months ago in my project and was able to generate apk but suddenly one day i got this error , i didn't update anything , does sdk tools updated automatically??